# How can I "place" a keylogger into a website? And see where the "click" has been done?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have made a quick website, it has a drop down menu/list and i would like to listen for the "click" and see what question they pick out of the 14 they could choose from. How would i go about this would it be better to code my own keylogger, or is there any recommend ones?

Comment: You don't need a keylogger, believe me...

Comment: keylogger seems  like overkill, just use AJAX

Comment: Of the 1,000 ways to get the selected value of a dropdown, using a "keylogger" would be at least #999.  It sounds like you are trying to get the user's selected "security question" for doing password resets or something equally sleazy.  Perhaps you would like to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a keylogger for that. If you pass the option to a PHP script, you can log the user's choice.

`<select name="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 </select>`

Depending on whether you're using `GET` or `POST` for your form submission, the result will be passed through `$_GET['mySelect']` or `$_POST['mySelect']`, with the `value="1"` as the value, in this case 1.